# Как в MySQL принять BLOB-данные из MS SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Фото лежит в MS SQL в поле типа IMAGE. Нужно передать его в MySQL в поле типа BLOB.
Правильно ли написана MySQL-функция , которая вызывается на стороне MS SQL для записи в MySQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_photo(_img BLOB) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Photo(img) VALUE(_img);
return LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Или так передавать BLOB-данные нельзя и нужно использовать, например, кодирование IMAGE -> BASE64 -> BLOB ?

Comment: а среда разработки какая? mysql не поддерживает oledb для "связаных серверов"  вроде бы... (mssql умеет передавать данные oledb совместимым базам напрямую). Нужно или через ADO+mssql или через более высокие языки, с++ c# js... Или в mysql добавили возможность импорта из mssql?

Comment: На стороне MS SQL находится 1С:Предприятие, которая и является пользователем MS SQL. А MySQL голая.

Comment: Синаксис: *INSERT INTO .. VALUE**S***...

Comment: Akina, так я так и написал. Выходит я написал рабочую функцию?

Comment: вы написали `VALUES` без `S`, не более того.

Comment: Так в чем ошибка-то? VALUE тоже допустимо, если вставляемая запись только одна.